# Google Chart API - Add percentage to pie chart label

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, google-pie-chart

I am trying to display a pie chart with label and percentage shown on each slice using google chart api. There doens't seem to be an option to display both label and percentage, so I have disabled the showing of percentage, and trying to manually add this to the label instead. However, when I use percentage symbol in the label, things are starting to act up.

How can I fix this?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/phpsriptkiddie/gscdymqp/1/

```
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Phase', 'link', 'percentage'],
      ['Phase 1 25%', '/link1', 25],
      ['Phase 2 25%', '/link2', 25],
      ['Phase 3 50%', '/link3', 50],
    ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 2]);
    var options = {
                pieSliceText: 'label',
      tooltip: {trigger: 'none'},
                slices: {
            0: { color: 'yellow', },
                        1: { color: 'green' },
            2: { color: 'grey' }            
                },
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart( document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(view, options);

    var selectHandler = function(e) {
     window.location = data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0]['row'], 1 );
    }

    // Add our selection handler.
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);

  }
```

Please notice how one label is shown, while the others aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the size of the chart area simply wasn't big enough! :-)
Issues were fixed as soon as I made it bigger.

```
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/phpsriptkiddie/gscdymqp/2/